# Next.js - next dev does not reflect changes in code

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image, next.js13

Im running thru some tutorials and after about an hour of searching, I cant seem to find a solution for this. Any changes I make to a specific component (navbar) is not being reflected in the dev server.

Im just trying to change and play around with the `Image` tag, but after saving in VScode, no changes are reflected, even in the Elements tab of Google dev tools.

**The changes are only reflected after I restart the dev server.**

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <div className="logo">
        <Image src="/logo.png" alt="nothing" width={122} height={78}/>
      </div>
    </nav>
);
}
 
export default Navbar;
```

Here are my versions and dependecies:

```
"packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "ninjalist",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "@next/font": "13.1.6",
        "next": "13.1.6",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0"
      }
    }
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

My dev server is running on port 3000, but previously I had the same problem in some other component, so I changed it to port 8000, following the solution of another thread.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 8000",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

After changing the port number, it works for 1 change, and then I have to restart the server again. Correct me if im wrong, but i dont think changing the port number did anything because I had to run npm run dev again anyways after editing the package.json file.

EDIT: Sharing my terminal and console output after saving the code

**VScode terminal where i run npm run build:**

```
    ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:8000, url: http://localhost:8000
event - compiled client and server successfully in 619 ms (236 modules)
wait  - compiling / (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 196 ms (242 modules)
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 208 ms (244 modules)
```

**Chrome console output after spinning up npm run dev:**

```
[Fast Refresh] rebuilding
hot-dev-client.js?1600:130 [Fast Refresh] done in 274ms
```

**Cleared the console and edited code, then saved:**

```
[Fast Refresh] rebuilding
```

Comment: 1. Share console output after you made any changes, is there a refresh triggered? 2. Have you made an changes to `next.config.js`

Comment: @AahanAgarwal I have edited the post to show my terminal and chrome console. I just realised that upon running npm run dev, it says "done". but after i clear it and do edits to code, it just sticks to "rebuilding".  Could this be the problem?

And no I have no made any changes to next.config.js

Comment: I think it freezes on `rebuilding` when there is some non page component in the `pages/` directory. Can you confirm if all files in the `pages/` are page components only?

Answer (score 2):

imported components names are case sensitive. this issue comes up when imported components case does not match it does not retender on change
for example

`import Image from 'next/Image';`
`import Link from 'next/Link';`

may be `I` of `Image` or `L` of `Link` component file name is in capital and you are using small image/link it will render the component first time without error but will not re render in case of change.